# Different query with similar type - will it refetch another query if one of these is update in cache?

Tags: graphql, apollo-client

I have two queries structure like this

```
1. query queryname{
     arr{
       id
       analysis
       __typename : "x"
    }
2. query query2{
        id
        otherthings
        __typename : "x"
    }

}
```

The first query gives an array of values, and second gives same item but returns single entity of same type. If I update first or second query in cache, will it also cause refetching the other query?